# Windows Phone Moving Button

Tags: windows-phone

I want to create a button on windows phone which have that moving like the tile or the application button on windows phone,when you press from the left the left side go down and the right side go up.

Comment: In order to make some exiting movements with transactional effects please review my awnser that uses MSFT Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to enable tilt property to acheive your purpose.

see below code,

add in your page.xaml file in declaration section add below namespace,

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

then set following attribute on button

```
toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the microsoft blend on your solution to make custom animations and make them start and stop whenever you want. Also you can give plysical parametrers and make it behave ad in real world with gravity or onother elastic movements...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012.aspx